# Apply lock to a postgres database

Tags: database, postgresql, locking, vacuum

I'm doing a vacuum full in my postgres server and I have some issues, so **I would like to lock all "postgres" database in my postgresql server**. 
I would not lock juste table.

How can I do that ?

thanks.

Comment: vacuum full locks table itself - what issue you have?..

Comment: If you want to keep users from connecting to the database, lock them out in `pg_hba.conf`, reload the server and kill all active connections.

Comment: @VaoTsun vacuum full blocks just table on which it works at a time T but other tables can be used and when it wants to take the lock it can't do it

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Okey I will try that, thanks

Comment: @Carlinto ah - I see -  makes sense

Comment: See [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/161922/1822) or [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/183982/1822) or [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/6122/1822)